# Trying to make a project

Tags: python

I am trying to make a thing where if you put in "a", "a", "b" it sorts it into a list a prints how many times you put in that number I am doing it so that it sorts it into a list and then counts how many items are in that list but whenever I put in "a", "b", "a" it will just print that I put a 3 times it will put all of the input into the last input

```
allLetters = (input("Enter a letter:\t"))

letters = []

while allLetters != "x":
    letters.append(allLetters)

    a = []
    b = []
    c = []
    d = []
    e = []

    for i in letters:
        if allLetters == "a":
            a.append(i)
        elif allLetters == "b":
            b.append(i)
        elif allLetters == "c":
            c.append(i)
        elif allLetters == "d":
            d.append(i)
        elif allLetters == "e":
            e.append(i)
        else:
            print("Not a valid letter!")

    allLetters = input("Enter a letter:\t")

length_a = len(a)
length_b = len(b)
length_c = len(c)
length_d = len(d)
length_e = len(e)

print("You put in a this many time: \t", length_a)
print("You put in b this many time: \t", length_b)
print("You put in c this many time: \t", length_c)
print("You put in d this many time: \t", length_d)
print("You put in e this many time: \t", length_e)
```

Comment: In your own words, when should `a = []` happen - only once before counting, or again before each time a new letter is considered? Why? Therefore, should it happen inside the loop, or before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` to outside of while loop. Move your `allLetters` input to while loop using walrus operator `:=` if you're using python 3.8+ to avoid repeated code. Iterate the `allLetters` not `letters` using for loop.

```
letters = []
a = []
b = []
c = []
d = []
e = []

while (allLetters := input("Enter a letter:\t")) != 'x' :
    letters.append(allLetters)
    for i in allLetters:
        if allLetters == "a":
            a.append(i)
        elif allLetters == "b":
            b.append(i)
        elif allLetters == "c":
            c.append(i)
        elif allLetters == "d":
            d.append(i)
        elif allLetters == "e":
            e.append(i)
        else:
            print("Not a valid letter!")

length_a = len(a)
length_b = len(b)
length_c = len(c)
length_d = len(d)
length_e = len(e)

print("You put in a this many time: \t", length_a)
print("You put in b this many time: \t", length_b)
print("You put in c this many time: \t", length_c)
print("You put in d this many time: \t", length_d)
print("You put in e this many time: \t", length_e)
print(letters)
```

Or you can use `list.count()`:

```
letters = []
while (allLetters := input("Enter a letter:\t")) != 'x' :
    for i in allLetters:
        if i in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']:
            letters.append(i)
        else:
            print("Not a valid letter!")

print("You put in a this many time: \t", letters.count('a'))
print("You put in b this many time: \t", letters.count('b'))
print("You put in c this many time: \t", letters.count('c'))
print("You put in d this many time: \t", letters.count('d'))
print("You put in e this many time: \t", letters.count('e'))
print(letters)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will count exactly how many times you put in each of the 5 letters in the inputs you've done.

```
letter = (input("Enter a letter:\t"))


letters = []
while letter != "x":
    letters.append(letter)
    letter = input("Enter a letter:\t").lower()

count_a = letters.count("a")
count_b = letters.count("b")
count_c = letters.count("c")
count_d = letters.count("d")
count_e = letters.count("e")

print("You put in a this many time: \t", count_a)
print("You put in b this many time: \t", count_b)
print("You put in c this many time: \t", count_c)
print("You put in d this many time: \t", count_d)
print("You put in e this many time: \t", count_e)
```

input:

a, b, a

output:

```
You put in a this many time:     2
You put in b this many time:     1
You put in c this many time:     0
You put in d this many time:     0
You put in e this many time:     0
```